# Removing fragment does not give previous fragment focus

Tags: android, android-fragments

When I use "add" for adding a new fragment, instead of "replace", I am unable to get focus to the original fragment (FragmentA) when returning with "remove". To add the new fragment, I use the following code:

```
Fragment fragment = new FragmentB();
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.frame_container, fragment, fragment.getClass().getName());
```

To return, I use the following code:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(FragmentB.this).commit();
```

Now, when I call a method that both fragments have, the fragment in FragmentB seems to be executing and crashing with NPE, where FragmentA should be called. How do I give focus to FragmentA after removing FragmentB?

Comment: Try using PopStackBack instead.Also you have to set that fragment to null, I mean if you keep the object referenced in any place.

Comment: I managed to solve it by adding `ft.addToBackStack(null);` before committing the transaction together with `getFragmentManager().popBackStack()`.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue by adding `ft.addToBackStack(null);` before committing the transaction together with `getFragmentManager().popBackStack()` when returning.

Comment: Turns out that it did not completely work, I needed to add a method which request focus to a layout in the fragment, which now works (bit of a hack though).